# apache multiple rewrite conditions to nginx

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

Can anyone help me with this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/search\/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([^/]*)\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=$1
```

I need to convert this for nginx

I tried this, but it won't work:

```
if ($request_uri ~* !^\/search\/.*) {
  if ($request_uri ~* !^\/index\.php$) {
    if ($request_uri ~* ^\/([^/]*)\.php$) {
      rewrite (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=$1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
if ($uri !~ "^/index.php$") {
  set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($uri !~ "^/search/.*") {
  set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($uri ~ "^/([^/]*).php$") {
  set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "321") {
  rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?page=$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `~* !` to `!~*`, and combine the last 2:

```
if ($request_uri !~* ^/search/.*) {
  if ($request_uri !~* ^/index\.php$) {
    rewrite ^/([^/]*)\.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=$1 redirect; 
  }
}
```

Or stick with location based rules:

```
location ~ /index\.php$ { } 
location ~ /search/.* { } 
location / { 
    rewrite ^/([^/]*)\.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=$1 redirect; 
}
```

Comment: The first one won't work, because nginx doesn't accept nesting.